# How to make realtime predictions in Spark Streaming with a pretrained h5py model from Keras?

Tags: apache-spark, keras, deep-learning, google-cloud-ml

I want to produce realtime predictions with a pretrained model. The data cannot fit in RAM so, I use Keras in Google Cloud ML to training and I want to use Apache Spark Streaming for predictions but I couldn't find any resources to be able to use pretrained models (h5py) in Spark streaming.

Another question is effiency of my strategy. Is there any better way for making predictions based on sensor data in realtime with a pretrained model? Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question duplicated? The referred link is for `Spark MLlib model` not Keras h5py model. Did apache-spark community just close any question they can't answer?